# Javascript str.match is not working in case to search in entire string?

Tags: match

Javascript match() is not working in case to search entire string?

Comment: show some code. what have you tried? what does "in case to search entire string" mean?

Comment: Wat? What is your code you want us to fix?

Comment: "Haven't you heard? Crowdsoucing to stackOverflow is the new trend in basic debugging." :P:P:P

Comment: Of course `match` does work up to the specification.

Comment: @GungFoo sadly, we can't debug this one

Comment: @JanDvorak that is probably a good thing

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. I think you misplaced the quotes in the function

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function myFunction()
{
var str="entire string"; 
var n=str.match(str); // var n=str.match('entire string');
alert(n)
}
</script>
```